# Universal Image Loader is too slow

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, universal-image-loader

I am trying to show images from URL.

In my code I used, `imageLoader.get` function but loading images are too slow.

```
imageLoader.get(c.getImgUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.mImage, R.drawable.img_loading, R.drawable.img_loading)); //450x200 px images.
```

Then I tried to compress but the problem is still alive.

```
imageLoader.get(c.getImgUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.mImage, R.drawable.img_loading, R.drawable.img_loading),225,100);
```

Besides, images are not shown in correct order firstly. When I scroll down(I show 20 images at the same time with recycler view), at first glance it shows images in wrong order. After 3-4 seconds, it shows correctly. Images changes automatically if I scroll down.

As a result, How can I solve my problem? How to speed up? How to show in correct order at first glance?

Comment: Please use Glide for Loading Image form url...

Comment: also check your code of Adapter that you are write in code

Comment: Do not use UniversalImageLoader. It was deprecated in 2015 and haven't received any updates since early 2016. It's dead. Use Glide instead. It's extremely well maintained and has loads of documentation. https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Glide for that which is far better in **memory consumption** than compared to other libraries. Also, it provides the **diskCacheStrategy**, **imageResizing**, **centerCropping**, **placeholder** for the image if not available and can set **error** image or message if error loading image occurs.

Below is the latest dependency you can include in you app level build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
```

Comment: What do you think about Picasso? Which one is better? Picasso or Glide?

Comment: I prefer Glide because of the above advantages, especially when compared to Picasso

Answer (score -1):

you can use Picasso image library easy to use 
http://square.github.io/picasso/